# How to call a function included in an index.html in a Backbone Marionette Collection

Tags: jquery, wordpress, backbone.js, marionette, gravity-forms-plugin

Very newbie question:

I follow David Sulc book Backbone.Marionette.js: A Serious Progression and try to learn Backbone and Marionette. I want to use WordPress Gravity Forms Web API as a RestAPI server since I do not know any server side language. In order to Authenticated, I need to include this JavaScript file to generate the rootUrl in the model and Url in the collection: (http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Web_API) The JavaScript portion.

So I need to include 2 script files in the index.html(located in the root folder) before  like this:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
```

Then in the collection(Located in js/entities/contact.js), I need to do this:

```
ContactManager.module("Entities", function(Entities, ContactManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
Entities.ContactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    calculateSig: function(stringToSign, privateKey){
        var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(stringToSign, privateKey);
        var base64 = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
        return encodeURIComponent(base64);
    },

    url: function(){
        var d = new Date,
         expiration = 3600 // 1 hour,
         unixtime = parseInt(d.getTime() / 1000),
         future_unixtime = unixtime + expiration,
         publicKey = "1234",
         privateKey = "abcd",
         method = "GET",
         route = "forms/1/entries";

        stringToSign = publicKey + ":" + method + ":" + route + ":" + future_unixtime;
        sig = this.calculateSig(stringToSign, privateKey);
        console.log(sig);

        return sig;
    },

    model: Entities.Contact

});
});
```

The first stupid question I have is how I can call the "CryptoJS.HmacSHA1" function and "CryptoJS.enc.Base64" within the calculateSig which within the Backbone Collection... If I use my namespace ContactManager.CryptoJS.HmacSHA1, it still says Cannot read property 'HmacSHA1' of undefined.

No idea how to implement Gravity Form authorization script to generate the url for backbone. Please help!

Comment: as i can see `CryptoJS` is a global var, also its expected that its undefined at `ContactManager.CryptoJS.HmacSHA1` as u haven't defined `CryptoJS` module in your Application. Also dont clearly understand why u use Collection for this form? will it be list of forms ?

Comment: If CrytoJS is a global var as I included in index.html, I should just be called 'var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(stringToSign, privateKey);' and it should work. But it does not (say undefined). That is why I am so confused. How can I use other JS file/function I included in a Marionette structure. BTW, I am listed the result records of a form. So it is a array/collection of records. I need to overwrite backbone.sync to do CRUD, each http action need a special "sig" attached on the URL...

Comment: Ops problem solved...my site is under https and I load the script via http which did not really load the CryptoJs script...

Comment: "...I do not know any server side language..." - you know JavaScript :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is my site is under SSL / HTTPS and I source the CryptoJS file with http. So my model / collection never get the global var.